# Lumen model timestamp different with data on table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen, laravel-query-builder

I have table called `teams` when I query using Eloquent like this following code:

```
$team = Team::where('id', 23)->get();
```

and this code return object like this following JSON:

```
{
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Test"
    "created_at": "2020-06-03 17:33:14",
    "is_used": false
}
```

but when I tried to direct query on workbench `created_at` field getting different value
The query look like this following mysql code:

```
SELECT created_at from teams where id = 23;
-- this query return 2020-06-04 00:33:14
```

But the valid value is ***the query with Eloquent***.

My question is how to make this default insert timestamp in mysql table equal with Eloquent data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What actual value insert in your database??

Comment: @A.A Norman I use default timestamp value from eloquent. So definitely I wasn't do `$team->created_at` when inserting record